# how to test simulation results for 256 point FFT written in verilog code

Tags: verilog

I have written verilog code for 256 point FFT(radix22 sdf) and testbench (which has random sample values...)
I got some simulation results how to know whether the results what i got are correct or not..

Comment: Maybe run the sample values through an FFT in Matlab or some other known good implementation and compare the results?

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard verification problem.

You need to get some "right answers" from somewhere and get your testbench to compare your code's output against them.

You can get the right answers in various ways:

- A tool such as Matlab if you have access to it would be very easy
- Take an existing C library like FFTW and run your data through that
- You could calculate them by hand (but I wouldn't recommend it as they are unlikely to be right first time :)

Take those outputs and convert them to a Verilog `$readmem` compatible file, read them into the simulator and compare the results at the end. Or write your results out in some form Matlab or whatever can work with and do the comparison there.